# Table information retrieval in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

ALL,

I just tried following query:

```
SELECT cols.column_name, cols.data_type, cols.character_maximum_length, cols.character_octet_length,
       cols.numeric_precision, cols.numeric_scale, cols.column_default, cols.is_nullable, 
       cols.ordinal_position, kcu.column_name
FROM information_schema.columns cols, information_schema.key_column_usage kcu
WHERE kcu.constraint_name = 'PRIMARY' AND kcu.table_schema = cols.table_schema AND
      kcu.table_name = cols.table_name AND cols.table_schema = 'draft' AND cols.table_name = 'leagues';
```

The last column of that query does return the primary key column name.

However, what I'd like to see instead is this:

- If the column is a primary key then the query will output '1' in the last query column.
- If the column is not a primary key, then the query will output '0' in the last query column.

Is there a function inside mySQL that will help me do that?

Thank you.

Comment: hi. I've posted an answer, which is not an... answer :-) I remembered, that some 13-16 years ago I also used the `FROM` on two on more tables. As you said, in the "old fashion". I don't remember anymore, why I did that. Then I would have maybe more to show or present.

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

The "function" is `case`:

```
SELECT cols.column_name, cols.data_type, cols.character_maximum_length, cols.character_octet_length,
       cols.numeric_precision, cols.numeric_scale, cols.column_default, cols.is_nullable, 
       cols.ordinal_position,
       (CASE WHEN kcu.column_name IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as pk_flag
FROM information_schema.columns cols LEFT JOIN
     information_schema.key_column_usage kcu
     ON kcu.constraint_name = 'PRIMARY' AND kcu.table_schema = cols.table_schema AND
        kcu.table_name = cols.table_name
WHERE cols.table_schema = 'draft' AND cols.table_name = 'leagues';
```

Comment: I appreciate your short, but very important statement about `from` AND `join`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, why? I just put table connection into the WHERE clause. I think its a MS "feature". Am I missing smth?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I just tried this query and it didn't work - I got 1 for every row. I just put this CASE statement into my query and run it inside Workbench

Comment: @Igor . . . Are you using `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, nope - `WHERE =`. I am a retro guy - I got an SQL introduction a long time ago and prefer the syntax I'm familiar with. I also see that 99.999% of all queries nowadays are written with `JOIN` - but what is wrong with `WHERE`?

Comment: @Igor . . . If you don't run the query in the answer, then you cannot say that it doesn't work.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, but you modified the query and therefore answered 2 questions instead of 1. I didn't ask to write proper "JOIN" - I asked how to make one field of the query produce the data I'm looking for. See the difference?

Comment: @aendeerei, it is completly out of context. There is nothing in the question which indicates I want "FROM ... JOIN". If I needed I would wrote it this way.

Comment: @Igor I think I've made myself misunderstood. My statement had nothing to do with the context of your question, nor with your code. Nor with the solution of @GordonLinoff. I just liked the form of his recommandation. That's it. Just today I've taken more time to test an example with a `FROM` statement on two tables. The results were surprisingly... wrong. Not the results i've expected, anyway. Doing a `JOIN` on those two tables resolved the problem elegant. I was also surprised, that someone used that two-tables-`FROM`. So don't take it personally, please.

Comment: @Igor Try creating 10 records in a `table1` (id & name). Then create 3 records in a `table2` (id & name). Now, make a `SELECT * FROM table1, table2`. Tell me please, if the result is not surprising! And then try with a `SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id=table1.id`. Tell me then the results. Exactly this example I tested. Maybe I was wrong, but I doubt.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I just tried to copy and paste your solution into the mySQL Workbench - it didn't work. It shows '1' for every column no matter whether it is a PRIMARY key or not.

Comment: @aendeerei, taking your example - the result will not be surprising at all. What would you expect to get if there will be no correlation between tables? If you can explain this with the screenshot, I will tell you why it is not surprising. You will also need to put "CREATE TABLE()" statements for both tables.

Answer (score 0):

This is the query I will use:

```
SELECT cols.column_name, cols.data_type, cols.character_maximum_length, cols.character_octet_length,
       cols.numeric_precision, cols.numeric_scale, cols.column_default, cols.is_nullable, 
       cols.ordinal_position, 
       (CASE WHEN kcu.column_name = cols.column_name THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as pk_flag
FROM information_schema.columns cols, information_schema.key_column_usage kcu
WHERE kcu.constraint_name = 'PRIMARY' AND kcu.table_schema = cols.table_schema AND
      kcu.table_name = cols.table_name AND cols.table_schema = 'draft' AND cols.table_name = 'leagues';
```

It works as expected in mySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This is not an answer to your question.*

@Igor, here are my tests regarding running a select query using `FROM` on two tables (`table1`, resp. `table2`), compared with a select command called by `LEFT JOIN`-ing the same tables.

As you mentioned, there is indeed a difference: `LEFT JOIN`-ing implies the existence of one or more relations between the tables, but `FROM`-ing do not (in the context).

My question is, why would/should data from uncorrelated tables be fetched?

**Table creation:**

---

```
-- Create table1 table.
CREATE TABLE `tests`.`table1` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

-- Create table2 table.
CREATE TABLE `tests`.`table2` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

**Value insertions:**

---

```
-- Insert values into table1 table.
INSERT INTO `tests`.`table1` (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('1', 'TAB1 1');
INSERT INTO `tests`.`table1` (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('2', 'TAB1 2');
INSERT INTO `tests`.`table1` (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('3', 'TAB1 3');
INSERT INTO `tests`.`table1` (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('4', 'TAB1 4');
INSERT INTO `tests`.`table1` (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('5', 'TAB1 5');
INSERT INTO `tests`.`table1` (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('6', 'TAB1 6');
INSERT INTO `tests`.`table1` (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('7', 'TAB1 7');
INSERT INTO `tests`.`table1` (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('8', 'TAB1 8');
INSERT INTO `tests`.`table1` (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('9', 'TAB1 9');
INSERT INTO `tests`.`table1` (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('10', 'TAB1 10');

-- Insert values into table2 table.
INSERT INTO `tests`.`table2` (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('1', 'TAB2 1');
INSERT INTO `tests`.`table2` (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('2', 'TAB2 2');
INSERT INTO `tests`.`table2` (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('3', 'TAB2 3');
```

**Table previews:**

---

[image: table1 preview]

[image: table2 preview]

**`FROM` query & result:**

---

[image: Query 1]

**`JOIN` query & result:**

---

[image: Query 2]

Comment: So what is so surprising? In first case you get a result of multiplying to matrices. Therefore each record will have all corresponding records from another table. In second case you are joining by the field equality, and so the result will be joining of the 2 tables.

Comment: @Igor, you say:  "_each record will have all corresponding records from another record_", but there is obviously no correspondence btw. the two tables. As long as you don't formally define one. The use of `FROM` without a `WHERE` clause gives a result missing "correctness" (`TAB1 6` has no corresponding `TAB2 1...3`) and beeing unneeded big. The only reason to use the `FROM` form (on two or more tables) correctly is to apply a `WHERE` clause, this way applying a relation and a filter. Then, one can say that `FROM...WHERE` can be used as an alternative to `LEFT JOIN...WHERE`.